# Search multiple column using multiple control in asp.net using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

```
Project_Detail pro = new Project_Detail();
string title=Ttitle.Text;
string year1=Tyear.Text;
string key = Tkeywrds.Text;
string area = Ddl_area.Text;
string categ = Ddl_catgry.Text;
string tech = Ddl_tech.Text;
string type =Ddl_type.Text;

var q = from obj in da.Project_Details
        where obj.Project_Title.Contains(title) 
              || obj.Submission_Date.Contains(year1) 
              || obj.Keywords.Contains(key) 
              || obj.Project_Area.Contains(area) 
              || obj.Project_Category.Contains(categ) 
              || obj.Project_Technology.Contains(tech) 
              || obj.Project_Type.Contains(type)
        select obj;

if (q != null)
{
    DetailsView1.DataSource = q;
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Literal1.Text = "Data not found";
}
```

this code give last record of table and also not give else condition result.
I want result of all condition and want to use LIke satatement.

Comment: if you want to use sql like : `SqlMethods.Like(obj.parameter)`.

Comment: If any of the search strings is empty, your query will return all elements, as `myString.Contains("")` always returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`q` is never null. It might be empty, though. So you should change your code to

```
if (q.Any()) // <<-----
{
    DetailsView1.DataSource = q;
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Literal1.Text = "Data not found";
}
```

Comment: its not working with multiple search option.its working with one query
like obj.Project_Title.Contains(title) this it is working
but when have multiple condition like
obj.Project_Title.Contains(title) || obj.Submission_Date.Contains(year1) || obj.Keywords.Contains(key) || obj.Project_Area.Contains(area) || obj.Project_Category.Contains(categ) || obj.Project_Technology.Contains(tech) || obj.Project_Type.Contains(type)
its not working .Its give all record which in the table 
Please Help ...

Comment: The problem is your `where` clause. If you have the profiler available, get the query and examine your data.

Comment: Linq query for multiple search operation with multiple control

Comment: The problem is your logic. What happens, if any of the strings to compare is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use count method `.Count()`

```
if (q.count()>0)
{
    DetailsView1.DataSource = q;
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Literal1.Text = "Data not found";
}
```

Comment: its not working with multiple search option.its working with one query
like obj.Project_Title.Contains(title) this it is working
but when have multiple condition like
obj.Project_Title.Contains(title) || obj.Submission_Date.Contains(year1) || obj.Keywords.Contains(key) || obj.Project_Area.Contains(area) || obj.Project_Category.Contains(categ) || obj.Project_Technology.Contains(tech) || obj.Project_Type.Contains(type)
its not working .Its give all record which in the table 
Please Help ...